# I want to show specific data using JSON Data in ReportViewer

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

This is my click event, this first two conditions work though (SI and DR) and they are showing on my ReportViewer. On the other hand, on the third condition I am aiming to show both SI and DR to ReportViewer, is it possible with this set of codes?

```
$(".btnViewReport").click(function () {
        const searchOption = $("input[name=searchBy]:checked").val();
        const account =  $("#ddlAccounts").val();
        const status = $("#ddlInvoiceStatus").val();
        const invoice = $("#ddlInvoiceType").val();
        const dateFrom = $("#txtStartDate").val();
        const dateTo = $("#txtEndDate").val();
        const searchTerm = $("#txtSearchTerm").val();

        if (invoice == "DR") {
            var obj = {
                searchOption: searchOption,
                account: account,
                status: status,
                invoice: "DR",
                dateFrom: dateFrom,
                dateTo: dateTo,
                searchTerm: searchTerm
            }
        }
        else if (invoice == "SI") {
            var obj = {
                searchOption: searchOption,
                account: account,
                status: status,
                invoice: "SI",
                dateFrom: dateFrom,
                dateTo: dateTo,
                searchTerm: searchTerm
            }
        }
```

I want to show both SI and DR using this part, I am open for your suggestions and tips because I am only new on using JSON

```
        else {
            var obj = {
                searchOption: searchOption,
                account: account,
                status: status,
                invoice: ["SI","DR"],
                dateFrom: dateFrom,
                dateTo: dateTo,
                searchTerm: searchTerm
            } 
        }

        viewReport(obj);
    });
```

```
function viewReport(obj) {
    showLoader("Loading...");

    $.ajax({
        url: '/reports/sales/customer/viewCompanySummary',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            SearchOption: obj.searchOption,
            Account: obj.account,
            InvoiceStatus: obj.status,
            InvoiceType: obj.invoice,
            DateFrom: obj.dateFrom,
            DateTo: obj.dateTo,
            SearchTerm: obj.searchTerm
        },
        dataType: 'html',
    }).done(function (resp) {
        $(".reportHolder").html(resp);
        swal.close();
    }).fail(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    });
}
```

For further understanding of the code please check the image below:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJnK4.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can recommend is to show the `InvoiceType` in your ReportViewer. For the first two conditions (SI and DR), just show `"SI" or "Sale Invoice"` and `"DR" or "Debit Invoice"` respective in `InvoiceType` column. And on the third condition where you need to show both SI and DR, just print `"Both"` in `InvoiceType` column.

Comment: Thank you for your good suggestion sir! Anyways, I've already fixed this issue through stored procedure in MSSQL by using IF conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed this code by, removing the conditional statements on this event.
And I retained the second code block.

```
$(".btnViewReport").click(function () {

        var accountCode = $("#ddlAccounts").val(), accountValidation = true;

        accountCode == "AVX" ? accountValidation = false : accountValidation;

        const accountName = accountCode;
        const searchOption = $("input[name=searchBy]:checked").val();
        const account = accountValidation;
        const status = $("#ddlInvoiceStatus").val();
        const invoice = $("#ddlInvoiceType").val();
        const dateFrom = $("#txtStartDate").val();
        const dateTo = $("#txtEndDate").val();
        const searchTerm = $("#txtSearchTerm").val();

        var obj = {
            accountName: accountName,
            searchOption: searchOption,
            account: account,
            status: status,
            invoice: invoice,
            dateFrom: dateFrom,
            dateTo: dateTo,
            searchTerm: searchTerm
        }

        viewReport(obj);
    });
```

Also, I've modified my stored procedure by adding conditional statements that seeks to ask the type of the Invoice used. Here's the sample code:

[image]

And here is the output:
[image]